# Possible to run 2 background tasks - Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app?

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I have a relative simple question: I have a BA that gets data from a remote API and generates a live tile in my Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app.

Now I also want to implement Push Notifications with WNS to set specific settings or alert the user (if the API is not working).

Can I just add 2 background tasks projects to my solution? (1 current BA for the live tile fetching, and 1 for the handling of Push Notifications).

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a simple test - registered two separate *BackgroundTasks* (separate Windows Runtime Components), fired upon *TimeTrigger* and sending simple Toast messages - bot are working.

So yes - it is possible to add more than one BackgroundTask to your solution.